# How to solve for imaginary numbers correctly in a quadratic in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a quadratic solver where it will tell me the values of x. It works flawlessly until one of the answers would be an imaginary number. How do I make it so the program doesn't crash every time and actually gives the correct answer in terms of i?

```
import math
print()
a = input("Coefficient of a: ")
a = float(a)
b = input("Coefficient of b: ")
b = float(b)
c = input("Coefficient of c: ")
c = float(c)

x_1 = (-b + math.sqrt(b ** 2 - (4 * a * c))) / 2 * a
x_2 = (-b - math.sqrt(b ** 2 - (4 * a * c))) / 2 * a
print()
print(f" X = {x_1} or {x_2}")
print()
```

Comment: Simply use `cmath` (complex math) instead of `math`. It will treat _all_ numbers as complex, but you can easily check whether `x.imag == 0` to see if a number is real.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`complex()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#complex) instead of [`float()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float):

```
a = input("Coefficient of a: ")
a = complex(a)
b = input("Coefficient of b: ")
b = complex(b)
c = input("Coefficient of c: ")
c = complex(c)

x_1 = (-b + (b ** 2 - (4 * a * c))**0.5) / 2 * a
x_2 = (-b - (b ** 2 - (4 * a * c))**0.5) / 2 * a
print()
print(f" X = {x_1} or {x_2}")
print()
```

Prints (for example):

```
Coefficient of a: 3+2j
Coefficient of b: 1
Coefficient of c: -2-1j

 X = (3.1748906833227015+8.198076043446118j) or (-6.174890683322701-10.198076043446118j)
```

Comment: Wow. I did not know `complex` existed.

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of `b ** 2 - (4 * a * c)`. If it's negative, you have imaginary solutions.

So your code becomes:

```py
import math
print()
a = input("Coefficient of a: ")
a = float(a)
b = input("Coefficient of b: ")
b = float(b)
c = input("Coefficient of c: ")
c = float(c)

delta = b ** 2 - (4 * a * c)
if delta >= 0:
    x_1 = (-b + math.sqrt(b ** 2 - (4 * a * c))) / 2 * a
    x_2 = (-b - math.sqrt(b ** 2 - (4 * a * c))) / 2 * a
    print()
    print(f" X = {x_1} or {x_2}")
    print()
else:
    print("The 2 solutions are imaginary:")
    real = -b
    imag = abs(math.sqrt(-delta) / (2 * a))
    print(f" X = {real} + i*{imag} or {real} - i*{imag}")
```

Comment: Is there any way to actually simplify radicals in python so that the solution would be a complex number like 2 + 3i instead of having to use a formatted string in the else statement?

Comment: Yes, there is. You just need to compute the actual values of `-b` and `sqrt(delta)/(2*a)`. I edited my answer to show you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use sympy this:example(Equation of the second and third degree and ...)

```
import sympy as sp
x = sp.Symbol("x")
print(sp.solve(x ** 4 - 1, x))
```

output:

```
[-1, 1, -I, I]
```

pip install sympy :https://pypi.org/project/sympy/